# postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

i wanna to make a query that select users that have same username and same hour of creation date by using postgresql database

Comment: Sorry, you have provided too little information to even begin answering the question. Start with details of your database schema ...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick. This will return any user/hour pair along with the count (untested):

```
select users.username, datepart('hour', users.created_at), count(*) from users
  inner join users u2 
    on users.username = u2.username
    and datepart('hour', users.created_at) = datepart('hour', u2.created_at)
group by users.username, datepart('hour', users.created_at) having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I guess that 'same hour of creation date' is meant as same absolute time within the same hour. So date_trunc('hour', users.created_at) would be the function of choice.

Comment: @incredible_Honk, absolutely. Use date_trunc instead of datepart.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*
from users u
join (
    select username, date_trunc('hour', creation_timestamp)
    from users
    group by 1, 2
    having count(*) > 1
) as x on u.username = x.username
order by u.username;
```

Should work nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your help it works fine and i wanna to  add a constrains that is creation date = today

Thanks